# Laravel 4 Pagination Relations

Tags: laravel-4, pagination

I am trying to display a list of products with their corresponding categories using the following in my controller:

```
return View::make('products.index')
->with('categories', Categories::with('products')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->Paginate(15))
```

But the pagination doesn't work, it's displayed all products (500+) while I want to show only 15 on each page. Here are my models:

Categories:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Products');
}
```

Products:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Categories');
}
```

How can I make the pagination work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categories = Categories::with(array('products' => function($query)
{
   $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');

 }))->paginate(15);

 return View::make('products.index', compact('categories'));
```

Hope it helps you. Here's the [link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) for eager loading.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand that what I want to accomplish doesn't work because it is displaying 15 products in each category, but all on the same page. I wanted to display 15 results ONLY on ONE page. But I guess I need to figure something else out :)

EDIT: It is actually displaying 15 categories, if I change it to 1 it is only displayed one category including all products. Thanks, I can work with this :)

Comment: No problem sir. Glad to help you